# Trouble to boot into OSX after install windows 10 on MacBook pro

Tags: mac, startup

Before this problem win + OSX  worked fine. But I tried to settings>recovery>Advance Startup from windows. after a restart , there is no two boot option . only windows boot option is appear. But how can I go to my previous duel boot option?
now I'm in windows 10.

Comment: What did you set in 'Advanced Startup' ?

Answer (score 1):

Press the`alt` or `option` buttons while pressing the power button to select Mac OSX or Windows

Comment: now it's not work...only show windows

Comment: Did you install Windows to the Mac partition by accident?

Comment: [NO](http://example.com)

Comment: No need to virtual shout... On Windows press the start key and the X key and select disk management and post a screen shot

Comment: [now  i want to back in os x](http://example.com)

Comment: [how can i do it ???](http://example.com)

Comment: [os x  deleted ....](http://example.com)

Comment: [please help ](http://example.com)